# How to add Campaign token in system contribution receipt

Tags: receipts

Trying to add the campaign name to my automatic receipts.

This works: {$formValues.campaign_id}

But this doesn't: {$formValues.campaign_name} or {$formValues.campaign_title}

I need to print the campaign name and not id.

How can I add the Campaign name to my receipt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get campaign id ({$formValues.campaign_id}) then you can use api to retrieve the Campaign Title. Use below snippet to get the Title

```
{if $formValues.campaign_id} 

  {crmAPI var='campaignTitle' entity='Campaign' action='getvalue' sequential=0 return="title" id="`$formValues.campaign_id`"}
  {$campaignTitle}
{/if}
```

> **Note**: The snippet code is not tested but you can use the logic to get
>   the title

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: thanks for the response. I tried this but it prints: Array
It seems to work in the API explorer but not in the template

Comment: It does work we need use right variable

Comment: Updated my answer